# Refactor parser code to avoid borrow checker issue

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

What the best way to refactor this parser code to avoid borrow checker issue?

```
pub type Token=u8;
pub trait Stream {
    type Item;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&Self::Item>;
    fn peek(&mut self) -> Option<&Self::Item>;
}

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Parser {
    input: Vec<Token>,
    position: usize,
}

pub type ParseError = String;
pub type ParseResult<T> = Result<T, ParseError>;

impl Stream for Parser {
    type Item = Token;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&Token> {
        let token = self.input.get(self.position);
        self.position += 1;
        token
    }

    fn peek(&mut self) -> Option<&Token> {
        self.input.get(self.position + 1)
    }
}

fn parse_expr(stream: &mut Parser) -> ParseResult<()> {
    match stream.peek() { // ~~ borrowed stream here
        None => Err(String::from("No more tokens")),
        Some(t) => match t {
            &0 => parse_number_literal(stream), // ~~ and here
            &1 => panic!("parse string"),
            &2 => panic!("parse character"),
            _ => Err(String::from("Unexpected Token")),
        }
    }
}

fn parse_number_literal(stream: &mut Parser) -> ParseResult<()> {
    let token = stream.next();
    Ok(())
}

fn main(){}
```

The compiler complaint about `cannot borrow`*stream`as mutable more than once at a time`. Reading other stackoverflow questions only answered why this problem occured but not how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `peek`function doesn't need a `&mut self`, and using just a `&self` would totally solve your error and give you `cannot borrow *stream as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable`. Anyway, avoiding `mut` when not needed is better.

Your issue is that you bind that `Token` reference to `t`, so the borrow doesn't end. You don't need to have a multi level `match`, and can do the same thing with

```
fn parse_expr(stream: &mut Parser) -> ParseResult<()> {
    match stream.peek() {
        None => Err(String::from("No more tokens")),
        Some(&0) => parse_number_literal(stream),
        Some(&1) => panic!("parse string"),
        Some(&2) => panic!("parse character"),
        _ => Err(String::from("Unexpected Token")),
    }
}
```

Or you could change peek to

```
fn peek(&self) -> Option<Token> {
    self.input.get(self.position + 1).cloned()
}
```

which would not create a borrow issue, but will clone the data.

Comment: thanks. refactoring the code to only single match helped.